# Find the maximum integer among three integers with Python

Tags: python, function

I need to write a function to find the maximum value among three inputs.

Ex: If the inputs are:

```
5
7
9
```

the output is:

```
9
```

Ex: If the inputs are:

```
-17
-8
-2
```

the output is:

```
-17
```

```
def max_magnitude(user_val1, user_val2, user_val3):
    if (user_val1 >= user_val2) and (user_val1 >= user_val3):
        max = user_val1
        
    elif (user_val2 >= user_val1) and (user_val2 >= user_val3):
        max = user_val2
    
    else:
        max = user_val3
    
    return max    
     
def main():
    user_val1 = int(input())
    user_val2 = int(input())
    user_val3 = int(input())
    
    print(max_magnitude(user_val1, user_val2, user_val3))
    

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LCQR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fix

For each condition `value is biggest` add the opposite `value is lowest`

```
def max_magnitude(user_val1, user_val2, user_val3):
    if (user_val1 >= user_val2 and user_val1 >= user_val3) or \
            (user_val1 <= user_val2 and user_val1 <= user_val3):
        return user_val1

    elif (user_val2 >= user_val1 and user_val2 >= user_val3) or \
            (user_val2 <= user_val1 and user_val2 <= user_val3):
        return user_val2

    return user_val3
```

---

#### Improve

- use `*args` as parameter, tp handle any amount of values
- use builtin `max`
- with key `abs` (absolute value).

```
def max_magnitude(*args):
    return max(args, key=abs)
```

`max(abs(i) for i in args)` doesn't work as it would return the absolute value of the answer, not the original value

Comment: Thanks for your help and it really helps me out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use "max" as a variable name
2. Do use `max()` as a function
3. Just change the function input to *args, then take the `max()` of the `abs()` of the tuple:

```
def max_magnitude(*args): 
    output = max(abs(i) for i in args)
    return output if output in args else -output
```

Test code:

```
def max_magnitude(*args): 
    output = max(abs(i) for i in args)
    return output if output in args else -output

n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())
n3 = int(input())

print(max_magnitude(n1, n2, n3))
```

Examples:

```
#inputs
> 5
> 7
> 9
#outputs
> 9

#inputs
> -2
> -8
> -17
#outputs
> -17
```

Comment: Eli, see my answer ;)